# Transfer big files from Azure Virtual Machine to Azure Storage

Tags: azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, file-transfer, bizspark

I have to big files range in size between 20 GB to 90 GB. I will download files with Internet Download Manager (IDM) to my Windows server at Azure Virtual Machine. I will need to transfer these files to my Azure Storage account to use it later. The total files size about 550 GB. 
Will Azure Storage Explorer do the job, or there are a better solution? 
My Azure account is a BizSpark one with 150 $ limit, shall I remove the limit before transferring the files to the storage account?
Any other advice?

Thanks very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at the AzCopy tool (http://aka.ms/AzCopy) - it is designed for large transfers of data to and from Azure Storage.

You will save network egress cost if your storage account is in the same region as the VM where you are uploading from.

As for cost, this depends on what all you are using. You can use the Azure price calculator (http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/calculator/) to help with estimating, or just use the pricing info directly from Azure website and calculate an estimated usage to see whether you will fit within your $150 limit.